# Transverse intersection of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the book geometry and topology by Bredon and I got quite confused with example 7.8, which says the following:

Consider $V = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3-\{0\}|z_1^3+ z_2^3 + z_3^3 =0 \}$. Note that $0$ is a regular value of $(z_1,z_2,z_3) \mapsto z_1^3 + z_2^2 + z_3^2$ of $\mathbb{C}^3 - \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, so that $V$ is a 4-manifold. Let $S = \mathbb{S}^5 = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3 | |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2  = 1\}$. Then, we claim that $V \pitchfork S$ and hence that $V \cap S$ is a 3-manifold.

My questions are: why is $V$ a 4-manifold? How can we make sure that $0$ is a regular value for the map proposed? Finally, would $S$ be a 3-manifold? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? For example, what happened when you tried to apply the definition of a regular value in order to see whether $0$ is a regular value for the map proposed?

Comment: Also, do you know the implicit function theorem? And do you know about transversality of manifolds?

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** (there are hints in the comments below the question), just a note aimed at clarifying the sentence in the book

> *Note that $\psi$ takes vectors tangent to $S$ into $0$*.

A more accurate rephrasing (using the notation of the book) would be

> *Note that $D_\lambda(\psi|_S)=0$, where $\lambda(t)=\phi(t+1)$, because $\psi|_S\circ\lambda\equiv1$.*